# Why does the Outlook To field only show the email address but not the contact name when the contact has been saved in the address book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

**Why does the Outlook To field only show the email address but not the contact name when the contact has been saved in the address book?**

Before: `To: Jim; Tom`

Now : `To:jim@aol.com; tom@aol.com`

When forwarding emails, the forwarding header also does not contain the contact name, which leads to poor readability of the header.

Some Outlook 2021 client is normal in some PC. but some Outlook 2021 client is abnormal in other PC, I don't know why.

Comment: In menu *File > Options > Mail*, is "Use Auto-Complete List to suggest names when typing in the To, Cc, and Bcc lines" set?

Comment: Hi @harrymc , Not here, currently this option is checked.

Comment: This may have something to do with the administrator's settings. In addition, when I send an email to a user in the organization, the display name is displayed in the To field, and when I send an email to an email outside the organization or to a personal account, the email address is displayed.

Comment: Hi @Soki, I am sending to the same person but this issue is happening in these days.

Comment: You can check the settings in File > Options > Mail, and make sure the option “Use Auto-Complete List to suggest names when typing in the To, Cc, and Bcc lines” is checked. This may help Outlook to recognize the contacts in your address book.

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: @Soki I have checked the settings in File > Options > Mail and made sure that the option "Use auto-complete list to suggest names when typing in the To, Cc and Bcc lines" is always selected. When I edit and send an email using the mail company's webmail interface, the recipient's name is normal. But when I edit and send email with Outlook 2021, it will only display address not name, even in edit mode it is name, it will display address after sending the email. I think it is a problem of Outlook 2021 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix this error:
Outlook Opitions - Add-Ins - Manage Com Add-Ins Go - uncheck below Add-Ins:

DGS Outlook Addin:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Agile DGS\bin\OEmailAddIn.dll
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Agile DGS\bin\OEmailAddIn64.dll

These two addins have a code functionality bug that filters email header and removes email address nickname.